# How to add event listener to an option inside a select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a select box

```
<select id="cartoons'>
 <option>Pogo</option>
 <option>Cartoon network</option>
</select>
```

I'm trying to add a mouseenter event to the second option like this

```
$("#cartoons").children().last().on("mouseenter", function () {
    alert("Hello world");
});
```

But it's not working. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qg730bp0/).

Comment: **You don't!**, options don't fire mouse events in all browsers, that's why you never attach mouse events to the options.

Comment: Might an "onselect" event be more appropriate for what you are doing?

Comment: But I want that event fired when I select that option. Is there a workaround?

Comment: All select elements have a `change` event, that's what you should be using to capture a selection, not mouseenter ?